# Why using an equality with a list doesn't work?

Tags: python

I tried for the last hour to do a basic thing with list, but it doesn't work, and I can't find out why

```
x = -5000
code = (str("{:07.0f}".format(abs(x)))
if code[3] == 5:
    print("1")
else:
    print("2")
```

When I run this, the value in code is 0005000. If I do `print(code_background_x[3])`, the output will be 5, but when I. run the program, the output is 2. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: ``code[3]`` is `"5"`, not `5`.

Comment: ok im just dumb , tanks for helping

Comment: No problem. Everyone can encounter this type of problems rarely. You can accept my answer as solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer doesn't have the green checkmark

Comment: oops my bad it does, I'm very tired today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`code[3]` is `"5"`, not `5`. Type of `"5"` is `str` while type of `5` is `int`. You can use builtin [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function for getting type of any object, which is good for debugging.

```py
x = -5000
code = str("{:07.0f}".format(abs(x)))
print(type(code[3])) # <class 'str'>
print("5" == 5) # False
```

You can also use [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) for debugging when you encounter this type of problems. It returns printable *representation* of an object.

```py
x = -5000
code = str("{:07.0f}".format(abs(x)))
print("5") # 5
print(5) # 5

print(repr("5")) # '5'
print(repr(5)) # 5
```

So this works:

```py
x = -5000
code = str("{:07.0f}".format(abs(x)))
if code[3] == '5':
    print("1")
else:
    print("2")
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enclose the `5` in quotes.

This works for me:

```py
x = -5000
code = str("{:07.0f}".format(abs(x)))
if code[3] == "5":
    print("1")
else:
    print("2")
```

Prints:
`1`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a `str` type object with `int`. It's apparent that types of both are not same. Probably you will wish to compare with `'5'`

```
x = -5000
code = (str("{:07.0f}".format(abs(x))))


if code[3] == 5:
    print("1")
else:
    print("2")

print(type(code[3]))
print(type(5))
```